# Javascript Object Key Value Confusion

Tags: javascript, object

apologies for the stupid question. I am trying to solve this Kata on Codewars, https://www.codewars.com/kata/the-enigma-machine-part-1-the-plugboard/train/javascript/. Its basically the beginnings of an Enigma machine. I feel like I made some good progess on it. Now I'm running it through pythontutor.com but I cannot for the life of me figure out why when I run this, the second iteration of the for loop changes the property 'A' of Plugboard into 'C' and **does not** create a new property 'C' with value of 'A'. I am sure this is a simple concept that I am completely missing, but I sure would appreciate any insight into this.

```
class Plugboard {

constructor(wires) {

if(wires.length % 2 !== 0 || wires.length === 0 || wires.length > 20){
   throw 'Error' 
}
   console.log(wires)
   this.str = wires.split('')

for(var i = 0; i < this.str.length; i += 2){
  if(this.hasOwnProperty(this.str[i])){
    throw 'Duplicate';
  }
    this[this.str[i+1]] = this.str[i];
    this[this.str[i]] = this.str[i+1];

  }
}

process(chr){
    if(!this.hasOwnProperty(chr)){
        return chr
    } else {
        return this[chr];
        }
    }  

}
var plugboard = new Plugboard("ABCA");
```

Comment: When I run that code I get `"B": "A",  "A": "C",  "C": "A"`` for `plugboard. Is that not correct or am i missing something?

Comment: It would be much better to quote the actual output you got, and the output you expected to get.

Comment: Again, sorry! The expected output is "B" : "A";  "A" : "B";  "C" : "A";  "A" : "C";.
What I am hoping to achieve is to create two key value pairs for each pair of characters. For example, if input = ('XY'), expected output this.X = 'Y' ; this.y = 'X'. I know there is something fundamental that I must be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The C property does exist and has a value of "A". I ran it on repl.it, and it just works...

```js
class Plugboard {

constructor(wires) {

if(wires.length % 2 !== 0 || wires.length === 0 || wires.length > 20){
   throw 'Error' 
}
   console.log(wires)
   this.str = wires.split('')

for(var i = 0; i < this.str.length; i += 2){
  if(this.hasOwnProperty(this.str[i])){
    throw 'Duplicate';
  }
    this[this.str[i+1]] = this.str[i];
    this[this.str[i]] = this.str[i+1];
  }
}

process(chr){
    if(!this.hasOwnProperty(chr)){
        return chr
    } else {
        return this[chr];
        }
    }  

}
var plugboard = new Plugboard("ABCA");
console.log(plugboard);
console.log("Value of C:",plugboard.C);
console.log("Value of A:",plugboard.A);
console.log("Value of B:",plugboard.B);
```

repl.it link: https://repl.it/GJg7/2

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you may have got the wording wrong in the question, and are actually worried about the `A` property containing the `C` value, not the reverse.

On the first loop we make the following assignments:

```
this["B"] = "A"
this["A"] = "B"
```

On the second loop we make the following assignments:

```
this["A"] = "C"
this["C"] = "A"
```

Note that this *overwrites* the existing value of `this["A"]`. It is not detected as a duplicate, because we only check `this.str[i]` and do not check if `this.str[i+1]` is a duplicate. It does not add a duplicate property, because we cannot have a duplicate property. It does exactly what it is told to do.

If this is not the desired behaviour, what is the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. I realised my mistake, I was overriding the property C on my second pass. Issue solved, thanks and sorry for my ignorance